# DynamoDB and Global Secondary Index and ObjectMapper

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use DynamoDBMapper to query a table, this table has a global secondary index. And, I wish to query the global secondary index. So, I have a class corresponding to each item in the table. And, the field which is the Hash key in the global secondary index is annotated as following

```
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName="Index-Name", attributeName = "EmailSent")
public String getEmailSent() {
    return emailSent;
}
```

And, I am querying using the mapper as shown below

```
public <T extends Object> List<T> queryGlobalIndex(final String tableName, final String indexName, final T inputObj) {

    final Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) inputObj.getClass();

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>().withIndexName(indexName).withConsistentRead(false).withHashKeyValues(inputObj);

    return mapper.query(clazz, queryExpression, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(
            new TableNameOverride(tableName)));
}
```

This is working, my quest is that I want to remove the field globalSecondaryIndexName from my annotation @DynamoDBIndexHashKey on the field. Any inputs on how to go about it?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the annotation? The mapper currently requires it to be able to figure out which attribute to pull off of the hash key object for the given GSI. I guess it could instead call *all* of the getters and hope that only one returns a non-null value? Not sure I love that idea.

Comment: i want to remove the annotation because it seems a bit like "hard coding". I want to say move the name of index to a property file instead of keeping it inside my java pojo annotation.

Comment: There's no support for doing this today. It sounds like a great feature request - can you pop open an issue on [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues)?